# Lua UTC time inconsistencies

Tags: time, lua, utc

Lua 5.1 doc says:

> If format starts with '!', then the date is formatted in Coordinated
>   Universal Time.

If format is `%c`, `!`'s behavior seems correct

```
local date_1 = os.date("!%c")
local date_2 = os.date("%c")
print("utc date: "..date_1)
print("not utc date: "..date_2)
```

If format is `*t`, `!`'s behavior seems swapped

```
local time_1 = os.time(os.date("!*t"))
local time_2 = os.time(os.date("*t"))
print("should be utc time, but is not: "..time_1) -- this should be UTC, and is not
print("should not be utc time, but is: "..time_2) -- this should not be UTC, but is
```

Dates are tested with: http://www.epochconverter.com/

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

The table returned by `os.date("!*t")` and `os.date("*t")` is correct. I'm printing only the `hour` field. Note that they are consistent with `%c` format:

```
local date_1 = os.date("!%c")
local date_2 = os.date("%c")
print("utc date: "..date_1)
print("not utc date: "..date_2)

print("utc date hour: " .. os.date("!*t").hour)
print("not utc date hour: " .. os.date("*t").hour)
```

Output on my machine (China Standard Time, UTC+08:00):

```
utc date: 02/06/15 02:02:29
not utc date: 02/06/15 10:02:29
utc date hour: 2
not utc date hour: 10
```

However, `os.time` takes the table, **assuming it's the local time**, and returns the epoch. So, the local time is converted to the real epoch, but the utc time is not.

```
print(os.time{year=1970, month=1, day=1, hour=8})
```

outputs `0` on my machine.